# Targeting shared mailbox with powershell to extract attachments

Tags: powershell, outlook

I am relatively new to powershell and I have a bit of a conundrum.  I have a script that a friend of mine helped me modify which goes through my email and looks for MSG attachments, extracts them to a temp folder, extracts an xls attachment from each, and converts it to a csv file (saving me insane amounts of time).  It works really well, as a whole, but it is targeting my default inbox and I want to modify it to target a shared mailbox instead.

this is the current outlook call;

```
$olFolderInbox = 6 
$outlook = new-object -com outlook.application; 
$ns = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI"); 
$inbox = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox) 
$messages = $inbox.items
```

Which I adapted from Sukhija Vikas Here(https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Outlook-Automation-using-d7584688)

I want to modify it further to look at a specific mailbox (ex: reports@company.com) so that I can have it get more messages than the ones that were accidentally sent to my primary email address.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

here is the whole script for reference;

```
##################################################################################### 
#             Author: Vikas Sukhija 
#             Date:- 09/12/2013 
#                       Description:- read emailbody,extract attachment & send email  
#            with extracted attachment 
#                       Prerequisites :- Powershell/Outlook 
##################################################################################### 
import-module msgutility 
###############################Logs################################################## 
<#$date = get-date -format d 
$date = $date.ToString().Replace(“/”, “-”) 
$time = get-date -format t 
#$time = $time.ToString().Replace(":", "-") 
$time = $time.ToString().Replace(" ", "") 

#$log1 = ".\Logs" + "\" + "Processed_" + $date + "_.log" 

#$logs = ".\Logs" + "\" + "Powershell" + $date + "_" + $time + "_.txt" 

Start-Transcript -Path $logs  

$date1 = get-date 
 #>
#############################outlook Call############################################# 
$olFolderInbox = 6 
$outlook = new-object -com outlook.application; 
$ns = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI"); 
$inbox = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox) 
$messages = $inbox.items 
write-host $messages.count 
$messcount = $messages.count 
#add-content $log1 $date1 
#add-content $log1 "Messages Count: $messcount" 
$countprocessed = 0 
foreach($message in $messages){ 
$msubject = $message.subject 
#add-content $log1 "Messages Subject: $msubject" 
$mBody = $message.body 
#Write-Host $mBody 
$mBodySplit = $mBody -split "Customer Email ID:" 
$toaddress1=$mBodySplit[1] 
$toaddress1 
#add-content $log1 "Vendor Email: $toaddress1" 

###################################Save Invoice####################################### 

$filepath = "c:\temp\" 
if ( $msubject -eq "Open/Closed Reports from iClose")
{
$message.attachments|foreach { 
    Write-Host $_.filename 
    $attr = $_.filename 
    #add-content $log1 "Attachment: $attr" 
    $a = $_.filename 
    If ($a.Contains("msg")) { 
    $_.saveasfile((Join-Path $filepath $a)) 
                             } 
  } 
$attachment = "c:\temp\" + $a 
}


}
set-location C:\Temp
Expand-MsgAttachment *

$xls = Get-ChildItem *.xls
foreach ($item in $xls)
{
ExportWSToCSV -excelFileName $item.FullName
}
```

***EDIT***

I have changed my outlook call to this;

```
$olFolderInbox = 6 
$outlook = new-object -com outlook.application; 
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI"); 
$recipient = $namespace.CreateRecipient("reports@mainspringservices.com")
$inbox = $namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox) 
$messages = $inbox.items 
write-host $messages.count 
$messcount = $messages.count 
#add-content $log1 $date1 
#add-content $log1 "Messages Count: $messcount" 
$countprocessed = 0 
foreach($message in $messages){ 
$msubject = $message.subject 
#add-content $log1 "Messages Subject: $msubject" 
$mBody = $message.body 
#Write-Host $mBody 
$mBodySplit = $mBody -split "Customer Email ID:" 
$toaddress1=$mBodySplit[1] 
$toaddress1
```

But am now getting this error:

```
Cannot find an overload for "GetSharedDefaultFolder" and the argument count: "1".
At C:\Users\Tyler\Documents\Windowspowershell\Powershell files\get-csvfromemail.ps1:30 char:1
+ $inbox = $namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

0
Load : The term 'Load' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path 
is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\Tyler\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\msgutility\msgutility.psm1:19 char:9
+         Load application
+         ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Load:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Namespace.CreateRecipient passing the name, call Recipient.Resolve, pass the Recipient object to Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder.

Comment: Thank you for your response Dmitry!  Like I said I am relatively new to all of this.  Would I add those strings in to get it to pass, or do I need to hash out/remove part of my original call?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. What strings? Your code is using GetDefaultFolder, you need to use GetSharedDefaultFolder, which in addition requires a Recipient object, which you can get from Namespace.CreateRecipient

Comment: I'm tripping myself up with the terminology.  I changed the code to this;

Comment: What did you change it to?

Comment: I added it to the original post under EDIT

Comment: GetSharedDefaultFolder take two arguments: $inbox = $namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder($recipient, $olFolderInbox)